# erasing the entire envrionment

Tags: c, unix, environment-variables

When I use the code `environ=NULL`, it means that I'm erasing entire environment for that process.

But I wonder why `envrion=NULL` means that it is erasing entire environment for that process.

Basically, environment variables are in the address space below the process's stack address range.

So, `environ` variable is indicating that address space, and `environ=NULL` means that `environ` is  just not indicating that address space anymore, I mean not erasing contents of memory which exists for environment variables.

But, why this means erasing entire environment??

Comment: If I'm getting you, you are right. Using that code you invalidate the environment, but address space still alive. As the [man](http://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Environment-Access.html) says: _The last element of the array is a null pointer._

Comment: It should be noted that this is **specific to Unix**. The C language itself has no notion of `environ`, defining `getenv()` to search an implementation-defined *environment list*. And even Unix defines (according to the manpage) that `extern char ** environ` "points to an array of pointers to strings", and that "the last pointer in this array has the value NULL", so `environ = NULL` is basically inviting undefined behaviour.

Comment: @John Bollinger Isn't `clearenv()` same as `envrion=NULL`, rather `*envrion==NULL`? So, when `environ=NULL`, `setenv()` or `putenv()` will make new environment list to point "name=value" string.

Comment: @A.Cho, after some deeper research I find I must retract my earlier comment in its entirety, and I will delete it presently.  On one hand, I made it under the mistaken impression that `clearenv()` was part of POSIX, but in fact it is not.  On the other hand, [POSIX *does* specify](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/) that "Any application that directly modifies the pointers to which the `environ` variable points has undefined behavior."  You may modify `environ` itself, but not the pointers to which it points.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The C standard library accesses the environment through the `environ` pointer. If you set that pointer to something different, that makes the standard library no longer find the previously set environment variables and thus has the effect of clearing the environment or setting it to whatever you set the `environ` pointer to.

Comment: actually, change the `environ` pointer does not stop the libraries from trying to use that pointer to find certain entities within the environment.  The probability of changing `environ` resulting is undefined behaviour (near) 100 percent.  Strongly suggest: Never change the contents of the `environ` variable.